# Reconstructing points based on the sum of their coordinates version 2

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

10 points are drawn on a piece of paper with the following rules:

- Each point has integer coordinates (,) that are between 1 and 10 inclusive.
- For each point there is exactly one other point with the same x-coordinate and exactly one other point with the same y-coordinate.

The sum of the coordinates of each point (ie., x+y) is provided: 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13. Can you reconstruct the location of each point? **Bonus question:** can you find multiple solutions? Good luck!

Comment: What exactly does "on top of each other" mean?

Comment: It means "Two points cannot have exactly the same location." I've fixed this.

Comment: How could they as the sums of coords are all distinct?

Comment: Good point. I will remove that condition.

Comment: There are exactly $470$ solutions out of $16329600$ possible, python script [here](https://tinyurl.com/puzzling-100996) and I'm working on the visual representation.

Comment: Wow that's great work Alexey!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> [image: 1]

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: A work of art ;-)

Comment: Wow that's truly beautiful and deserves the tick!

Comment: NIce. How long did it take you to draw all of them by hand? :)

Comment: @Marius python source code [here](https://github.com/megabyte0/python/blob/master/puzzling/100996/100996.py), took a couple of hours. The most indirect part was selecting the colors. Btw, can anyone suggest better colors? Maybe from XOY color space, not from RGB.

Comment: TBH, the color doesn't add very much to the diagram, at least for this (red/green color-blind) viewer. The components are just too small.  Maybe if you shaded entire strips instead of just lines?

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't look anywhere near unique to me:

For example,

> you can make an "L" shape from the first 6 points $(1,1),(2,2),(1,4),(2,4),(6,1),(6,2)$ and a rectangle from the remaining 4 $(7,3),(8,3),(7,5),(8,5)$ or $(4,6),(5,6),(4,8),(5,8)$ or $(3,7),(5,7),(3,8),(5,8)$ or $(3,7),(4,7),(3,9),(4,9)$

or

> a "fat L" $(1,1),(3,1),(1,4),(3,3),(4,3),(4,4)$ and a rectangle $(5,5),(5,6),(7,5),(7,6)$ or $(5,5),(6,5),(5,7),(6,7)$

or

> another disfigured L $(1,1),(3,1),(1,6),(2,6),(2,3),(3,3)$ and a rectangle $(5,5),(6,5),(5,7),(6,7)$ or $(6,4),(6,5),(8,4),(8,5)$ or $(8,2),(8,4),(9,2),(9,4)$ or etc.

or for a slightly different class of solution

> with the $(1,1)$ piece participating in a rectangle instead of an L: $(1,1),(1,4),(9,1),(9,4)$ and $(2,2),(2,5),(4,2),(3,5),(4,8),(3,8)$

and probably more

Comment: You got it. Well done!

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Out of interest: do we know these are essentially all? Or do we not know and not care? Or do we know they aren't all and still don't care? Because so far I didn't do anything systematic, just throwing stuff against the wall and see what sticks...

Comment: The solution I had was a single component (similar to tehtmi answer, but not the same). I was not aware of other solutions, but assumed that they are possible, like you have demonstrated.

Answer (score 4):

I confirm @AlexeyBurdin's count of 470 solutions, which I obtained via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $S=\{2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13\}$ be the set of desired sums.  Let binary decision variable $p_{x,y}$ indicate whether there is a point with coordinates $(x,y)$, let binary decision variable $r_x$ indicate whether row $x$ contains any points, and let binary decision decision variable $c_y$ indicate whether column $y$ contains any points.  The constraints are:

\begin{align}
\sum_{x,y} p_{x,y} &= 10 \\
\sum_{y} p_{x,y} &= 2 r_x &&\text{for all $x$}\\
\sum_{x} p_{x,y} &= 2 c_y &&\text{for all $y$}\\
\sum_{\substack{x,y:\\ x + y = s}} p_{x,y} &= 1 &&\text{for all $s\in S$} \\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you Rob. It is always great to get a confirmation from you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with "one component":

> ```
>  (1,1) 2
>  (1,9) 10
>  (2,9) 11
>  (2,4) 6
>  (4,4) 8
>  (4,8) 12
>  (5,8) 13
>  (5,2) 7
>  (3,2) 5
>  (3,1) 4
> ```

Comment: That one is certainly more interesting than my various "L"s'n'squares

Comment: This was similar to the solution I had in mind, but not identical to it.